# I have an error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'price' error by rendering the template

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have these models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=300, choices=TOTAL)
    subcategory = models.CharField(max_length=300, choices=SUBPRODUCT)
    price = models.FloatField()
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def imageURL(self):
        try:
            url = self.image.url
        except:
            url = ''
        return url




class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    date_ordered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
        
    @property
    def shipping(self):
        shipping = False
        orderitems = self.orderitem_set.all()
        for i in orderitems:
            if i.product.digital == False:
                shipping = True
        return shipping

    @property
    def get_cart_total(self):
        orderitems = self.orderitem_set.all()
        total = sum([item.get_total for item in orderitems])
        return total 

    @property
    def get_cart_items(self):
        orderitems = self.orderitem_set.all()
        total = sum([item.quantity for item in orderitems])
        return total 

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    @property
    def get_total(self):
        total = self.product.price * self.quantity
        return total
```

My views.py:
def store(request):
data = cartData(request)

```
cartItems = data['cartItems']
order = data['order']
items = data['items']


context = {'cartItems':cartItems, 'order':order, 'items':items}
return render(request, 'store/store.html', context)
```

It's my template:

```
<div class="bottom">
<div class="total">
                                            <span>Total</span>
                                            <span class="total-amount">${{order.get_cart_total|floatformat:2}}</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <a href="{ url 'checkout' }" class="btn animate">Checkout</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

As I mentioned above, I have this error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'price'  error  by rendering the template. At the beginning it was working. I added 2 products and It worked. But, after adding products, it's giving this error. I tried many times, but each time I'm getting this error. Please help

Comment: Why is `OrderItem.product` nullable? Your issue is that one of your instances has this null and you are not handling it

Answer (score 0):

As @IainShelvington suggested why you have set OrderItem.product nullable? Though you want it as it is, you can try the code below in the OrderItem model.

```
@property
def get_total(self):
if self.product and self.quantity: # handling case when either value is Null.
    total = self.product.price * self.quantity
    return total
else:
    return 0
```